# Как запустить нужные фрагмент при уничтожения Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня вопрос в следующем. Я получаю push уведомления. по клику по нему я перехожу SecondActivity, я уничтожаю его, нажимая назад(делаю finish()). Запускается MainActivity, где находиться контейнер и подгружается фрагмент А, мне нужно фрагмент Б. Вопрос  как запустить нужные фрагмент при уничтожения активити?

Comment: на кнопку назад повесить `startActivity()` с неким передаваемым параметром и при запуске `MainActivity` проверять его и в зависимости от его значения атачить нужный фрагмент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `Activity` есть два прекрасных метода для этого

1. Сначала запускаем новую активити с помощью [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))
2. Потом в перекрытом методе [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) получаем результат и отображаем что надо.

Примеры кода здесь: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities